# JQuery chaining actions, works..but CSS doesn't wait it's turn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

so i have something like so (below), everything works in turn (it's hidden at the start, then you see it slide down, waits 2 seconds, and slides back up)  but the .css action takes place immediately, even though it's after the 2 second delay.  Just wondering why this is.

```
$('p:first')
   .hide()
   .slideDown('slow')
   .delay(2000)
   .css({"background-color":"#ff4"})
   .slideUp('slow')
});
```

**EDIT NEW CODE:**  I have changed my code to this: which doesn't seem to slideUp anymore.. (as I want it to change to yellow right before sliding up)

```
   $('p:first')
.hide()
.slideDown('slow')
.delay(2000, function(){
                $(this).css({"background-color": "#ff4"})
                })
.slideUp('slow')
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only affects the animation queue. Method chaining occurs as soon as the previous call returns, so [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) (which is not an animation) ends up being called too soon.

You can pass a callback function to [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), and it will be called when the animation is complete:

```
$("p:first").hide()
            .slideDown("slow")
            .delay(2000)
            .slideUp("slow", function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#ff4");
            });
```

**EDIT:** You're trying to pass a callback to `delay()` in your second code snippet, but that method does not officially support such an argument (it still gets called, though, which is interesting). However, doing that breaks the animation callback chain, as you can see, since `slideUp()` is never called.

In this situation, you can inject your own function in the animation queue, using the aptly-named [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) methods:

```
$("p:first").hide()
            .slideDown("slow")
            .delay(2000)
            .queue(function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#ff4")
                       .dequeue();
            }).slideUp("slow");
```

Comment: so the reason slideUp() waits for slideDown() to finish, is because there is a set delay already built in?

Comment: Indeed. All the animation methods only enqueue an effect and return immediately. `slideDown()` queues a `slow` slide effect, `delay()` queues a delay to run after that animation, and `slideUp()` queues another `slow` slide effect to run after the delay.

Comment: thank you, I have edited my original post.  As I want to see the yellow right before it slides back up

Comment: I agree it would be quite useless otherwise :) See my updated answer.

Comment: ahh, so you can queue things that wouldn't normally be part of the queue.  Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The ".css()" call is a synchronous operation, but all the others are animations. The animation functions all return immediately after queueing up the operation for later.

There's a way to queue up your own code in the animation queue, I think, but I won't type in a guess; I'll make a quick check of the documentation.

*edit* — ok what you'd do is this:

```
$('p:first')
   .hide()
   .slideDown('slow')
   .delay(2000)
   .queue(function(next) 
     $(this).css({"background-color":"#ff4"});
     next();
   })
   .slideUp('slow')
});
```

Seems like using the callbacks as others suggested should work too.

Comment: excellent, now only if I knew all the synchronous operation compared to non-synchronous

Comment: Ha ha yes :-)  Generally you can assume if the method you're calling does something like an animation over time, it'll involve the separate "animation queue" that "slideUp()" and friends all use.

Answer (score 2):

Change the css in the callback

```
$('p:first')
   .hide()
   .slideDown('slow')
   .delay(2000)
   .slideUp('slow',function(){
       $(this).css({backgroundColor:"#ff4"})
   })
```